# How to remove the base Lablel use javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, html

My website is reverse proxy google (I am in china ,cannot access google  ),
like  this url :

> "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=zh_CN&continue=https://myaccount.google.com/intro"

I want to  remove the base Lablel  use javascript?,But my method doesn't work,Maybe I did something wrong, I don't know why.Thank you very much for any help.

my js method :

`document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<base href.*?>','')`

Original code like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-CN" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <base href="https://accounts.google.com/">
```

I expect output :

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="zh-CN" dir="ltr">
    <head>
```

Comment: You're missing the delimiters in your regex, instead of `'<base href.*?>'`, try `/<base href.*?>/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to clear contents of head tag, this should do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = ''
```

If it's just base tag then:

```
const headTag = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const baseTag = headTag.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
headTag.removeChild(baseTag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the element with `querySelector` and remove it.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('base');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh-CN" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <base href="https://accounts.google.com/"/>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('base');
elem[0].href = '';
```